# For a VLAN aware bridge, do you assign the native VLAN to the bridge itself or a vlan interface?

Tags: debian, networking, bridge, vlan, ifupdown

Given a vlan-aware bridge in which I have a multitude of (tagged) vlans. VLAN1 is the management VLAN and untagged.

The machine hosts lots of VMs/containers which are part of one more VLANs; the host machine itself, I would like add to the (untagged) management VLAN 1.

Is the correct configuration to assign the IP directly to the bridge, like this (as in "old" bridge configs)?

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.227.1.20/24
        gateway 10.227.1.1
        bridge-ports enp3s0 enp4s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 1-4094
        bridge-pvid 1
```

Or, do I need/should add a separate vlan interface, like this?

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
        bridge-ports enp3s0 enp4s0
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 1-4094
        bridge-pvid 1

auto vmbr0.1
iface vmbr0.1 inet static
        address 10.227.1.20/24
        gateway 10.227.1.1
```

For the latter option, that would certainly make sense to me for any tagged VLAN, but since VLAN1 is untagged, I am not sure if this is right. (Note, it works, but I am not sure of hidden issues in case that's not the right way)

Comment: As a remark, only PVID 1 works correctly with `ifupdown2` tools on the bridge: https://github.com/CumulusNetworks/ifupdown2/issues/216 . I'd rather not trust ifupdown2's configuration and verify the actual resulting configuration (with iproute2 tools) each time. As you're using PVID 1, you're not affected.